# Difference between int and numbers.Integral in Python

Tags: python

I'm trying to get a deeper understanding in Python's data model and I don't fully understand the following code:

```
>>> x = 1

>>> isinstance(x,int)
True

>>> isinstance(x,numbers.Integral)
True

>>> inspect.getmro(int)
(<type 'int'>, <type 'object'>)

>>> inspect.getmro(numbers.Integral)
(<class 'numbers.Integral'>, <class 'numbers.Rational'>, <class 'numbers.Real'>,
 <class 'numbers.Complex'>, <class 'numbers.Number'>, <type 'object'>)
```

Based on the above, it seems that `int` and `number.Integral` are not in the same hierarchy.

From the Python reference (2.6.6) I see

> numbers.Integral - These represent elements from the mathematical set of integers (positive and negative).

What's the difference between `int` and `numbers.Integral`? Does it have something to do with the `type int` vs `class numbers.Integral` I see in the above output?

Comment: `numbers.Integral` is an abstract class, you can't instantiate it. Unlike `int`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`numbers` defines a hierarchy of abstract classes that define operations possible on numeric types. See [PEP 3141](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3141/). The difference between `int` and `Integral` is that `int` is a concrete type that supports all the operations `Integral` defines.

Comment: I've read about the type hierarchy for numbers and about ABCs. The fact that I don't see `int` and `numbers.Integral` on the same hierarchy is that `int` does not derive from `number.Integral` but it is registered as a "virtual subclass". Correct? I see the relation between them, from `numbers.Integral` towards `int`, in `numbers.Integral._abc_registry` but is it possible to see the other side of the relation also (from `int` towards `numbers.Integral`)?

Comment: @ElenaT: `number.Integral` is a model (or a concept). `int` is an implementation of that model. That's how they're related. Inheritance is orthogonal to the issue.

Comment: I read through PEP 3141, and I still do not understand why issubclass(int, numbers.Integral) returns true, but inspect.getmro(int) does not list Integral as a base class.  It seems to me that the method resolution order necessarily includes numbers.Integral.  Thus, my only conclusion at this point is some sort of built-in optimization for int().  I was unable to determine the meaning of a Python 'model' or 'concept', but I do see that both int and numbers.Integral are Python classes.

Comment: Is this analogous to the concept of an interface in Java?

Answer (score 5):

**Allow me to add two things:**

```
isinstance(x,numbers.Integral)
```

also covers `long` and

```
isinstance(x, int)
```

does not. The `numbers.Integral` test would be closer to

```
isinstance(x, (int, long))
```

in Python 2 (Python 3 killed `long` for good.)

I prefer the test with `numbers.Integral`, because if you derive from `int` (or `long`), `isinstance(y, numbers.Integral)` will still be `True`.

Comment: If you subclass `int` (or `long` on Python 2), `isinstance(subclass_instance, (int, long))` would still be true. The difference is if you are working with another Integral type that defines all the same methods but does not inherit from `int` or `long`, such as numpy integers. `isinstance(np.int64(), (int, long)` will always be False, while `isinstance(np.int64(), numbers.Integral)` will return True.

Answer (score 5):

TLDR: `int` [is registered](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/numbers.py#L389) as a [virtual subclass](https://docs.python.org/3/library/abc.html#abc.ABCMeta.register) of `numbers.Integral`.

```
# numbers.py:380 (CPython 3.8)
Integral.register(int)
```

`numbers.Integral` is an abstract definition of what integral numbers must provide. `int` is a concrete implementation of integral numbers.

---

The `isinstance` and `issubclass` functions are not restricted to inheritance. For example, they can express [structural type relations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structural_type_system) such as `collections.abc.Iterable`:

```
>>> class MyIterable:
...     def __iter__(self): ...
...
>>> issubclass(MyIterable, collections.abc.Iterable)
True
```

In fact, both `isinstance` and `issubclass` can be [changed for each type](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#customizing-instance-and-subclass-checks). The standard library uses this to define [Abstract Base Classes (ABC)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/abc.html) support both concrete subclasses (via inheritance) and virtual subclasses (via [`cls.register(subclass)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/abc.html#abc.ABCMeta.register)).

A virtual subclass is not related to its ABC via inheritance -- its method resolution order thus does not use the ABC. In specific, `int` does not *inherit* any methods for `numbers.Integral`. However, it does *implement* all public methods and operations required for `numbers.Integral` independently - thus satisfying the `numbers.Integral` definition.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. One clarification question: Since `numbers.Integral` cannot be instantiated (because it's an ABC), can it even implement any of its methods?

Comment: ‘However, it does implement all methods required for `numbers.Integral` independently’ Except the `__complex__` method.

Comment: @Maggyero I've adjusted the wording to avoid that pitfall.

Comment: `__complex__` is part of the interface so I think it is a bug (it is the only method of the `numbers` ABCs that is not available in the built-in types).

Comment: @Maggyero What is and isn't a bug is something to discuss [on the issue tracker](https://bugs.python.org/issue47083), I would say.

Answer (score 4):

```
In [34]: numbers.Integral ?
Type:           ABCMeta
Base Class:     <class 'abc.ABCMeta'>
String Form:    <class 'numbers.Integral'>
Namespace:      Interactive
File:           c:\python26\lib\numbers.py
Docstring:
    Integral adds a conversion to long and the bit-string operations.


In [35]: int ?
Type:           type
Base Class:     <type 'type'>
String Form:    <type 'int'>
Namespace:      Python builtin
Docstring:
    int(x[, base]) -> integer


In [36]: type(int) == type (numbers.Integral)
Out[36]: False

In [39]: issubclass(int, numbers.Integral)
Out[39]: True
```

Integral is an Abstract Base Class. `int` is a subclass of the ABCMeta `Integral`