# How to implement the lazy slicing of a class instance?

Tags: python, class, slice, python-class, object-slicing

I am building a class which has underpinning it a list of `int`s, its `__getitem__` method is then a reasonably computationally involved function outputting a list of potentially large size. Here is the code:

```
Class A(list):

    def __init__(self, n):
        self.li = [i for i in range(0, n)]
        super().__init__(self.li)
        self._ind = 0

    def __getitem__(self, item):

        assert (type(item) is int and item >= 0) or type(item) is slice

        if type(item) is slice:
            start, stop, step = item.start, item.stop, item.step
            if stop is None:
                stop = len(self)
            if step is not None:
                for i in range(start, stop, step):
                    yield self[i]
            else:
                for i in range(start, stop):
                    yield self[i]

        if item == 0 or item == 1:
            return []

        out = []
        while item != 1:
            if super().__getitem__(item):
                p = super().__getitem__(item)
            else:
                out.append(item)
                return out

            if p not in out:
                out.append(p)
            item //= p
        return out
```

My code is currently not working as it always returns a generator, and this messes up iterating over an instance of the class. However upon slicing, I do not wish it to do all the computations and store it, as this would make it consume a lot more memory. An example of what I wish to do:

```
from math import prod

test = A(10**7)
out = 0
for i in test[10**6:10**7]:
    out += prod(i)
```

How can I make slices work efficiently?

Comment: Thank you for the edits, they have clarified a lot.

Comment: Why do you have that specific check for `item == 0 or item == 1` in your `__getitem__()`?

Comment: In the original version of the code, self.li is not the range(0,n) but is an array of the smallest prime factor of k. So self.li[15] = 3. In the case of 0 and 1 this is not existent and is instead set to zero. So in these cases it would return an error. 

The short answer is it's a legacy of the purpose I was originally writing it for and I did not remove it when I was condensing my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of returning a generator, return a *view*. This is an object that conceptually represents the sequence of elements in question. We can do this by storing a reference to the original A instance, plus a range that encodes the instances. When we index into the view, we can ask the range which original index (or indices) are involved.

Supposing we set up the general structure:

```py
class A(list):
    def __init__(self, n):
        super().__init__()
        self[:] = [i for i in range(0, n)]

    def _at(self, idx):
        # custom logic here to return the correct value for self[idx]

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        if isinstance(idx, int):
            return self._at(idx)
        elif isinstance(idx, slice):
            # The `indices` method of a slice object converts to
            # start, stop, step values which we can use to construct a range.
            return A_view(self, range(*idx.indices(len(self))))
        else:
            raise TypeError # this is not an appropriate use for `assert`
```

Then our view could look like:

```py
class A_view:
    def __init__(self, original, indices):
        self._original, self._indices = original, indices


    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        if isinstance(idx, int):
            return self._original[self._indices[idx]]
        elif isinstance(idx, slice):
            return A_view(self._original, self._indices[idx])
        else:
            raise TypeError

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self._indices)
```

The idea is that if we receive an integer index, we translate it through the `range` object into an index for the original `A`, and call back to its `__getitem__` (with an integer this time). If we receive another `slice`, we use it to slice our range into a sub-range, and make another view.

Note that your A class should already be iterable, due to inheriting from `list`. To make the view iterable (and also get the `in` operator, forward and reverse iteration, `.index` and `.count` methods for free), you can inherit from `collections.abc.Sequence`. You just need a `__getitem__` and `__len__` - both easy to implement, as above - and the base class will do the rest (while also advertising to `isinstance` that your class has these properties).

Comment: You left out the definition of the `self.li` attribute, which — if you do it like the OP did — will result in a potentially *huge* (as in having 10**7 elements) list being created. This means the cleverness of returning an `A_view` instance might be for naught…

Comment: I omitted it because, as `A` is already a subclass of `list`, it makes more sense to actually use the storage provided that way (`self[:] = ...`). I assumed that the initial values there were in some way necessary to the calculation. Of course, that may not be necessary; but in that case, it could very well be that there is no good reason to inherit from `list`, either.

Comment: It hard to image that the calculation of the value at a random index would depend on the sequential integer values coming before or following it — but I suppose anything's possible. Regardless, if you're going to leave it in, then you need to add the code that defines its value before it's used.

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean. I forgot to fix the `super` call accordingly. The intent is to use the `self`'s own contained elements, rather than those of an attribute. Should be fixed now.

Comment: Thank you, this seems like a very neat solution, I will try it out.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not totally sure what you're asking. Does this work for your use case? Items will be generated lazily and not stored (unless the caller stores them).

```
class LazyCollection:

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        if isinstance(key, int):
            return self.get_single_item(key)

        elif isinstance(key, slice):
            def my_generator():
                for index in slice_to_range(key):
                    yield self.get_single_item(index)
            return my_generator()


    def get_single_item(self, index):
        # (Example! Your logic here.)
        return index * 10


def slice_to_range(my_slice):
    '''
    More options for implementing this:

    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13855288/turn-slice-into-range
    '''
    start = my_slice.start if my_slice.start is not None else 0
    stop = my_slice.stop
    step = my_slice.step if my_slice.step is not None else 1
    return range(start, stop, step)


coll = LazyCollection()

# Get a single item
print(coll[9999])

# Get a slice
for x in coll[2:10]:
    print(x)
```

Output:

```
99990
20
30
40
50
60
70
80
90
```

Comment: Thank you, this solves my prolem perfectly!